# Bitcoin Exchanges for Self Directed IRA LLC

Tags: exchanges

I have a self directed IRA with control through an LLC for funding purposes. Has anyone registered with a bitcoin exchange in the name of their LLC and if so, which exchanges are user friendly for setting up such an entity?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Coinbase was easy and only took a couple of days. I provided ALL required information and it was simple. I also established one with Binance no problems there.